# Estimate the limit or bounds of the smallest eigenvalue of a symmetric Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I have a symmetric matrix $K\in \mathbb{R}^{(2N+1)\times(2N+1)}$, with $i,j=-N,\dots,N$,

$$ K_{ij}=-\frac{N}{2\pi[{(i-j)}^2-1/4]} $$

Because the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant with positive diagonals, all eigenvalues are positive. I want to know if the limit of the smallest eigenvalue

$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\lambda_0$$

exists. Numerical tests suggest that $\lambda_0\approx0.58$ increases very slowly with $N$. How can I prove that the limit exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Observation 1

Minimum eigenvalue can be computed as the lower bound of the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient):
$$
R_N(x) \equiv \frac{(x, K^{(N)} x)}{(x, x)}\\
\lambda_0^{(N)} = \min_x R_N(x) 
$$

For large $N$ the smallest eigenvector (blue) looks like a bell-shaped function, somewhat similar to parabola (orange).

[image]

Let's try to estimate $\lambda_0$ from above computing $R(x)$ on a quadratic function.
Taking $x_i^{(N)} = 1 - \left(\frac{i}{N}\right)^2$ and using *Mathematica* to compute sums give
$$
(x^{(N)}, Kx^{(N)}) = \frac{(16N^2 - 1) H\left(2N + \frac{1}{2}\right)+8N (8N^3 + N (\log
   16-5)-1)+2-\log 4}{32\pi N^3} \gtrsim \frac{2N}{\pi}, \quad N > 1\\
(x^{(N)}, x^{(N)}) = \frac{16 N^4 - 1}{15 N^3} \lesssim \frac{16 N}{15}.
$$
Here $H(n) = \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx$ is a harmonic number function and $H(n) = \gamma + \log n + O(n^{-1})$.

So,
$$
R_N(x^{(N)}) > \frac{15}{8\pi}, \quad N > 1\\
\lim_{N \to \infty} R_N(x^{(N)}) = \frac{15}{8\pi}.
$$

If $\lim_{N \to \infty} \lambda_0^{(N)}$ exists, then it cannot exceed $\frac{15}{8\pi} \approx 0.596831$.

#### Observation 2

[Gershgorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) gives a lower bound on the minimal eigenvalue for diagonally dominant matrices.
$$
\lambda_0^{(N)} \geq \min_{i \in [-N, N]} K_{ii}^{(N)} - \sum_{j \neq i} |K_{ij}^{(N)}|
$$
The minimum is attained at $i = 0$ and is equal to
$$
K^{(N)}_{0,0} - \sum_{j \neq 0} |K^{(N)}_{0,j}| = 
\frac{4N}{2\pi} - 2\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{N}{2\pi (j^2 - 1/4)} = \\ =
\frac{2N}{\pi} - \frac{N}{\pi}\frac{4N}{2N+1} =
\frac{2N}{\pi (2N+1)} \to \frac{1}{\pi} \approx 0.3183.
$$

#### Update

On evaluating $(x, Kx)$. Summating by diagonals we get
$$
(x, Kx) = \sum_{i,j=-N}^N K_{ij} x_i x_j = 
\frac{2N}{\pi} \sum_{j=-N}^N x_j^2
- \frac{N}{\pi}\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{s^2 - 1/4} \sum_{j=-N+s}^N x_j x_{j-s}.
$$
For $x_i = 1 + \frac{i^2}{N^2}$:
$$
\sum_{j=-N}^N x_j^2 = 
\sum_{j=-N}^N \left(1 - 2\frac{j^2}{N^2} + \frac{j^4}{N^4}\right) = 
\frac{16N^4 - 1}{15 N^3}.
$$
Sum of powers $j$ may be easily computed from [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).
$$
\sum_{j=-N+s}^N x_j x_{j-s}
= \frac{(2N - s - 1) (2N - s) (2N - s + 1) (4N^2 + 6 N s + s^2 + 1)}{30 N^4}
$$
This is basically a 5-th degree polynomial in $s$, so we need to compute
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{s^k}{s^2 - 1/4}, \quad k = 0, 1, \dots, 5.
$$
To evaluate the sum let's [divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) $s^k$ by $s^2 - 1/4$:
$$
s^{2q} = P_{2q}(s) (s^2 - 1/4) + R_{2q}\\
s^{2q+1} = s P_{2q}(s) (s^2 - 1/4) + s R_{2q}\\
$$
For even powers the remainder is a constant, while for the odd powers the remainder is a linear term in $s$.
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{s^{2q}}{s^2 - 1/4} = \sum_{s=1}^{2N} P_{2q}(s)  + R_{2q} \sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{s^2 - 1/4} \\
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{s^{2q+1}}{s^2 - 1/4} = \sum_{s=1}^{2N} s P_{2q}(s)  + R_{2q} \sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{s}{s^2 - 1/4}.
$$
Next,
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{s^2 - 1/4} =
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \left(\frac{2}{2s-1} - \frac{2}{2s+1}\right) = ({\rm telescoping}) = 2 - \frac{2}{4N+1}.
$$
And the most complex sum,
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{s}{s^2 - 1/4} =
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \left(\frac{2s}{2s-1} - \frac{2s}{2s+1}\right) = 
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2s-1} - 1 + \frac{1}{2s+1}\right) = \\ =
\sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{2s-1}
+ \sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{2s+1} = 
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{s-1/2} +
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{s=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{s+1/2} = \\ =
1 + 
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{s=2}^{2N} \frac{1}{s-1/2} +
\frac{1}{4N+1} +
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{s=1}^{2N-1} \frac{1}{s+1/2} = 
1 + \frac{1}{4N+1} +\sum_{s=1}^{2N-1} \frac{1}{s+1/2}.
$$
The last sum may be expressed via [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments):
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{2N-1} \frac{1}{s+1/2} = \frac{1}{3/2} + \frac{1}{5/2} + \frac{1}{7/2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(4N-1)/2} = \\
= (H_{3/2} - H_{1/2}) + (H_{5/2} - H_{3/2}) + \dots + 
(H_{(4N-1)/2} - H_{(4N-3)/2}) = ({\rm telescoping}) = \\ =
H_{(4N-1)/2} - H_{1/2} = H_{(4N-1)/2} - 2 + \log 4.
$$
In principle, one could do all of it by hand, but CAS like *Mathematica* do it faster and without errors (usually).

#### Update 2. Observation 3

For this section I would move the $-\frac{1}{2\pi}$ factor to the right hand side.

The matrix problem
$$
K u = -2\pi \lambda u, \quad u \in \mathbb R^{2N+1}
$$
is an approximation for an eigenvalue problem for an integral operator with hypersingular kernel:
$$
\mathcal K[u](x) \equiv \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{u(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy.
$$
Consider a grid defined as
$$
x_i = ih, \quad i = -N, \dots, N.
$$
It will be referred to as collocation points. Here $h \equiv \frac{1}{N}$ is the grid step. Consider also functions
$$
\psi_i(x) = \begin{cases}
1, &|x - x_i| \leq \frac{h}{2},\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
These functions will be referred to as piecewise constant basis functions.

The discretization idea it to search solution in form
$$
u_h(x) = \sum_{k=-N}^N c_k \psi_k(x),
$$
i.e. the solution is sought as a linear combination of piewise-constant basis functions. Coefficients $c_k$ are found by exact equality of $\mathcal K[u_h](x) = -2\pi \lambda u_h(x)$ at collocation points:
$$
\mathcal K[u_h](x_i) = -2\pi\lambda u_h(x_i), \quad i = -N,\dots,N.
$$
A minor correction is necessary to have a full match between this method and the original matrix problem. The integral operator integration domain needs to be expanded by $h/2$:
$$
{\mathcal K}_h[u](x) \equiv \int\limits_{-1-h/2}^{1+h/2} \frac{u(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy.
$$
Let's obtain matrix formulation from $\mathcal K_h[u_h](x_i) = -2\pi\lambda u_h(x_i)$. On the right hand side we have simply $c_i$ since all other terms in sum vanish. On the left side we have
$$
\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k \int_{-1-h/2}^{1+h/2} \frac{\psi_k(y)}{(y-x)^2}dy = 
\sum_{k=-N}^N c_k \int_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k+h/2} \frac{1}{(y-x)^2}dy.
$$
Integrals are hypersingular and need to be treated accordingly. When $x$ is outside of $[x_k - h/2, x_k + h/2]$ there is no singularity in the integration domain, so
$$
\int_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k+h/2} \frac{1}{(y-x)^2}dy = 
-\left.\frac{1}{y-x}\right|_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k+h/2} = 
\frac{1}{x_k-x-h/2} - \frac{1}{x_k-x+h/2} = \\ =
\frac{h}{(x_k-x+h/2)(x_k-x-h/2)} = \frac{h}{(x_k - x)^2 - h^2/4}.
$$
So for $i \neq k$ we have
$$
\int_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k+h/2} \frac{1}{(y-x_i)^2}dy = 
\frac{h}{(x_k - x_i)^2 - h^2/4} = 
\frac{N}{(k - i)^2 - 1/4}.
$$
Now let's consider the singular case:
$$
\int_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k+h/2} \frac{1}{(y-x_k)^2}dy = \\ =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[
\int_{x_k-h/2}^{x_k-\epsilon} \frac{1}{(y-x_k)^2}dy + 
\int_{x_k+\epsilon}^{x_k+h/2} \frac{1}{(y-x_k)^2}dy -
\text{ signular terms in } \epsilon
\right] = \\ =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[
\int_{-h/2}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^2}dy + 
\int_{\epsilon}^{h/2} \frac{1}{z^2}dy -
\text{ signular terms in } \epsilon
\right] = \\ = 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[
-\frac{2}{h} + \frac{1}{\epsilon}
-\frac{2}{h} + \frac{1}{\epsilon}
-\text{ signular terms in } \epsilon
\right] = \\ = -\frac{4}{h} = \frac{N}{(k-k)^2 - 1/4}.
$$
So the discrete problem has the following form
$$
\sum_{k=-N}^N \frac{N}{(i-k)^2 - 1/4} c_k = -2\pi\lambda c_i, \quad i = -N, \dots, N.
$$

I do not consider myself proficient in numerical solving of the hypersingular integral equations, but it seems that the lowest eigenpair of the discrete problem approximates the corresponding eigenpair of
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{u(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy = -2\pi\lambda u(x)\\
u(-1) = u(1) = 0.
$$
Numerical experiment confirms $O(h)$ convergence (that is $\lambda_0^{(N)} = \lambda_0 + c h + O(h^2)$):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
N & \lambda_0^{(N)} & \lambda_0^{(N)} - \lambda_0^{(N/2)} = -ch + O(h^2)\\\hline
10 & 0.537368328299425 & -\\
20 & 0.557608872089796 & 0.02024054\\
40 & 0.5681282883636342 & 0.01051942\\
80 & 0.5734807004118339 & 0.00535241\\
160 & 0.5761778623915926 & 0.00269716\\
320 & 0.5775311031471828 & 0.00135324
\end{array}.
$$

Looking at the eigenvector I've noticed the square-root-like behavior near $x=\pm 1$. By some trials and errors I found a function $\frac{\cos \frac{\pi x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ that is very close to the eigenvector:
[image]

Let's search $u(x)$ in form $\sqrt{1-x^2} s(x)$ where $s(x)$ is a smooth function. The modified equation has the form
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} s(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy = -2\pi\lambda \sqrt{1-x^2} s(x)
$$
Following this [review](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337285194_Hypersingular_Integrals_in_Integral_Equations_and_Inequalities_Fundamental_Review_Study) let's express $s(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k U_{2k}(x)$, where $U_m(x)$ are the [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} s(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy.
$$
Let's evaluate the integrals $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy$. First, let's reduce it from hypersingular to singular by integration by $x$:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy = 
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-1}^1 
\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{y-x} dy.
$$
This integral is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Relations_between_the_two_kinds_of_Chebyshev_polynomials):
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{y-x} dy = 
-\pi T_{2k+1}(x).
$$
Taking derivative by $x$ and noting $T_n'(x) = n U_{n-1}(x)$ we get the relation for hypersingular integral:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2} U_{2k}(y)}{(y-x)^2} dy = 
-\pi (2k+1) U_{2k}(x).
$$
This greatly simplifies the original problem which now becomes
$$
-\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (2k+1) U_{2k}(x) = 
-2\pi \lambda \sqrt{1-x^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k U_{2k}(x),\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (2k+1) U_{2k}(x) = 
2 \lambda \sqrt{1-x^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k U_{2k}(x).
$$
Note that $U_{2k}(x)$ are orthogonal with weight $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Let's integrate both sides with $U_{2m}(x)$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (2k+1) \int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) dx
= 2 \lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = 2\lambda c_m \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
We got another eigenproblem for $\lambda$ and $c_k$:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k (2k+1) \int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) dx = \lambda c_m.
$$
By multiplication with $\sqrt\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}$ the problem becomes symmetric for unknown $d_m = \sqrt{2m+1} c_m$:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k \sqrt{(2k+1)(2m+1)} \int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) dx = \lambda d_m.
$$
Its matrix is
$$
A_{k,m} = \frac{\sqrt{(2k+1)(2m+1)}}{\pi} \int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) dx.
$$
Product of $U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x)$ is expressable in terms of sum:
$$
U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) = \sum_{p=2|k-m|}^{2k+2m}
U_p(x).
$$
By integrating we get
$$
\int_{-1}^1 U_{2k}(x) U_{2m}(x) dx = \sum_{p=|k-m|}^{k+m}
\frac{2}{2p+1}.
$$
Then the matrix takes its final form
$$
A_{k,m} = \frac{2\sqrt{(2k+1)(2m+1)}}{\pi} \sum_{p=|m-k|}^{m+k} \frac{1}{2p+1}.
$$

Truncating the matrix to $M \times M$ size and solving the corresponding finite-dimensional problem we obtain a sequence of eigenvalues
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
M & \lambda_0^{(M)} & \lambda_0^{(M)} - \lambda_0^{(M/2)}\\\hline
5 & 0.578898528414741 & -\\
10 & 0.578887652711596 & -1.088 \cdot 10^{-5}\\
20 & 0.578886985185902 & -6.675 \cdot 10^{-7}\\
40 & 0.578886944510590 & -4.068 \cdot 10^{-8}\\
80 & 0.578886942013462 & -2.497 \cdot 10^{-9}\\
160 & 0.578886941859036 & -1.544 \cdot 10^{-10}\\
320 & 0.578886941849439 & -9.598 \cdot 10^{-12}
\end{array}
$$
The $\lambda_0^{(M)} - \lambda_0^{(M/2)}$ decreases by approximately $16$ times when $M$ is doubles. This means that this method has 4-th order convergence (and I have no idea why it is 4-th).

A notable property is that eigenvalue estimates are decreasing. This is a consequence of [eigenvalue interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), since truncated matrix $A$ with size $M \times M$ is embedded in truncated matrix of size $(M + 1) \times (M + 1)$ so $\lambda_0^{(M+1)} < \lambda_0^{(M)}$.

The limiting eigenfunction normalized by $u_0(0) = 1$ is approximately
$$
u_0(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} (0.92051141827 - 0.08051912092 (4x^2 - 1) - 0.001599248738 (16 x^4 - 12 x^2 + 1) + \dots).
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot, this solves my problem, but can you elaborate a little more on the (x^N, Kx^N) part? Where do the H(n) and log functions come from? Did mathematica give this result?

Comment: @noir Yes, that result was from Mathematica, but I've described how it could be obtained by hand

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @noir Just for your info. I've added some details on related integral equation. I hoped for a closed-form solution, but alas.